# Excel Date Type

Tags: excel, vba

I have a **column of Dates** in my Excel Spreadsheet.  When the Dates are generated, the **Format is 2015/27/04**.  However the column has been formatted as a **“General”**.  When I try and change the **format to “Date”** I am getting an output of **“########”**.  Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Have you tried making the column wider?

Comment: If they look like that with a General format, they are not true dates - they're stored text. (which wouldn't surprise me as that isn't a typical date format.)

Comment: An external system generates the Dates into the excel spreadsheet. Yes I have tried to widen the column that not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Image tutorial how change format](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Date-Formats-in-Microsoft-Excel)

[Video tutorial how change format](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=nIta_PW7XVo)

If there's just one cell, click on it.
If they are in a column, left-click your mouse on the letter above the column to select and format the entire column.
If they are in a row, left-click your mouse on the number beside the row to select and format with the section (or cell) highlighted to bring up the editing menu. Select "Format" on the bar at the top of the screen. Select "Cells..." from the drop menu.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to change and run this short macro:

```
Sub Formatter()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, "/")
        If UBound(ary) = 2 Then
            r.Clear
            r.Value = DateSerial(ary(0), ary(2), ary(1))
            r.NumberFormat = "yyyy/dd/mm"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To use this from within another sub, we must modify *Formatter*:

```
Sub Formatter(rng As Range)
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In rng
        ary = Split(r.Text, "/")
        If UBound(ary) = 2 Then
            r.Clear
            r.Value = DateSerial(ary(0), ary(2), ary(1))
            r.NumberFormat = "yyyy/dd/mm"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

and supply a **calling routine:**

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Fund Trend").Range("A11:A60")
    Call Formatter(rng)
End Sub
```

Comment: @James What did you see??

Comment: @Gray'sStudent I am getting an error with block not set . i am using this range Sheets("Fund Trend").Range("A11:A60")

Comment: @Gray'sStudent Apologies for the late reply, I am getting a run time error of "application-defined  or object - defined error.  its on  r.Value = DateSerial(ary(0), ary(2), ary(1))